# Page very slow @first load (using magento with varnish)

Tags: performance, magento, load, varnish

Im running a magento store with varnish.
When browsing my page for the first time (in 24 hours or so), the first page load is extremely slow (10 sec).
After that if i click links n stuff everything is fine... its only the first contact.
Here i got a chrome console screenshot of the network:
http://skc.5e5.de/q.jpg
Does someone have an idea what the reason could be?

Comment: You should provide at least HTTP headers for the slow resource (you can find them clicking the resource name) in order to trace the issue. Your VCL would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your non-cached is too slow and it is warming (likely you are on $20-50/mth servers), Varnish will not help you, unless your non-cached is 2-3s Google will penalise you and most visitors will abandon their carts. Hosting for Magento should be 1% of revenue, anything less and it will not work, technology can only take you so far, the rest is actually doing it correctly, and that needs the hosting budget.